# str_to_date for ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, strftime

so I have to insert a bunch of records from a data source that has dates in the format 
    `Sun, Sep 13 1:00 PM.`

I'm just going to execute SQL that uses 
    `STR_TO_DATE`

But I was wondering in case I need it in the future if you guys know of a way to do this using a ruby method...like a reverse strftime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, look at [`Datetime.strptime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/DateTime.html#M002796) and the nearby `Datetime.parse` (similar methods for Date).

Pretty much any language that uses the C strftime will have strptime as well.

Comment: hmmmmmm i thought i looked through the Date and Time ruby functions but i guess i should be more thorough and less stack overflow trigger happy. thanks anyway though!

Comment: It helped that I knew what to look for -- I went straight to strptime. Note that it is a class method, not an instance method.